# cakePHP 3 custome registration and hashing errors

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

(I'm new to cakePHP 3 so be gentle :-) )

I play with Auth and build the Examples. Now I have two problems.

My first problem: The password hashing don't work (He insert the passwords as plain text). Maybe because I changed the fields.
My second problem: How can I check if the mail is already in use (exists in Database) before he save the new record.

Here is my Code

**Model/Table/UsersTable.php**

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table{

 public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->table('fc_admin_login');
}
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
return $validator
 ->notEmpty('log_mail', 'Geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail ein')
 ->notEmpty('log_pw', 'Geben Sie ein Passwort ein')
 ->add('repeat_password', 'no-misspelling', [
     'rule' => ['compareWith', 'admin_login_password_hash'],
                 'message' => 'Passwords are not equal',]);
         }}
```

**Model/Entity/User.php**

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{

protected $_accessible = [
  '*' => true,
  'id' => false
];

protected function _setPassword($password)
{
  return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}}
```

**Controller/UsersController.php**

```
public function add()
{     
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) 
        {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Inserted'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Error'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

**Template/Users/add.ctp**

```
<div class="panel-body">
                 <?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <?= $this->Form->label('log_mail', 'Mail'); ?>
                                        <?= $this->Form->input('log_mail', array('type' => 'email', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'name@provider.com', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <?= $this->Form->label('log_pw', 'Ihr Passwort'); ?>
                                        <?= $this->Form->input('log_pw', array('type' => 'password', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => '********', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <?= $this->Form->label('repeat_password', 'Repeat pw'); ?>
                                        <?= $this->Form->input('repeat_password', array('type' => 'password', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => '********', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <hr/>
                                <?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-block']); ?>
                                <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mutator on your entity has the wrong field name or you have the wrong name of field in your form.  You either need to correct the form name or the mutator name.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->label('password', 'Ihr Passwort'); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => '********', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
</div>
```

OR

```
protected function _setLogPw($password)
{
  return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

To check for uniqueness of fields add a buildRules method to your table like so:

```
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['log_mail']));

}
```